# jpa query syntax using spring petclinic sample and hsqldb

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, spring-mvc, jpa

I am using the [Spring PetClinic application](https://github.com/SpringSource/spring-petclinic/) to learn Spring and Hibernate programming, and I am trying to return a list of cat owners using JPA.  I have thus added a findByPetType() method to the OwnerRepository and JpaOwnerRespository classes.  My question is how to write the query.  I am using the hsqldb database for the moment.  Here is my code so far:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
public Collection<Owner> findByPetType(String typeID) {
    // using 'join fetch' because a single query should load both owners and pets
    Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets WHERE pet.type_id LIKE :typeID");
    query.setParameter("typeID", typeID + "%");
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

I plan to later output a separate web page listing cat owners, another listing dog owners, etc.  For each of those pages, I will have a table with owner name, address, and pet names of the specific type indicated by the page constraint (cat or dog or etc only.)

Can anyone show me how to change the query above so that it will return the result set that I desire?

I just want to get the findByPetType() method right now.  I will take a stab at putting the rest of it together myself if I can start with a good query.  And where can I read up about this syntax?  It seems to be mixing java object references with database elements, if I am understanding it correctly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may be missing an *as* clause that tells Hibernate that `owner.pets` shall henceforth be referred to as `pet`. Try changing your code like so:

```
Query query = this.em.createQuery("SELECT DISTINCT owner FROM Owner owner left join fetch owner.pets as pet WHERE pet.type_id LIKE :typeID");
```